# Migrating pimcore v 6.9.6 to pimcore 10.6.3 v, facing key, value issue

Tags: symfony, pimcore, php-8.1

Im updating pimcore v 6.9.6 to 10.6.3v.

Initially did all the changes to the folder structures manually and executed this command `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` composer update

While migrating I'm getting below error

> [error] Migration Pimcore\Bundle\CoreBundle\Migrations\Version20210107103923 failed during Execution. Error: "Please provide select options as associative array with fields "key" and "value"
>
> In Select.php line 206:
> Please provide select options as associative array with fields "key" and "value"

[image]

I'm using php 8.1 v and mysql 8.0v, composer version is 2.5v.
[image]

select.php its in vendor folder showing:

```
public function setOptions(?array $options) {
    if (is_array($options)) {
        $this->options = [];
        
        foreach ($options as $option) { 
            $option = (array)$option;
            
            if (!array_key_exists('key', $option) || !array_key_exists('value', $option)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide select options as associative array with fields "key" and "value"');
            }
            $this->options[] = $option;
        }
    } else {
        $this->options = null;
    }
    
    return $this;
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of the section in Select.php?

Comment: I have added code in above statement..
but i have printed all the option provider data , its all printing expected type of array. Even i debugged removing all the options provider and class definition. Still the same issue exists.

Comment: i have solved this issue, but now i have different issue =>   Cannot retrieve the container from a non-booted kernel. 

anyone faced this issue?